# How to get help on Rmarkdown chunks options?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I started to play with Rmarkdown and I'm loving it. But I have newbbie question that, ridiculous or not, I can't find a straight forward answer:

I can't figure where in knitr documentation or elsewhere I can learn what are the useful things to write in the chunks insert to tell R what to plot or not. E.g:

````
```{r warnings=FALSE, message=FALSE}
````

Will prevent R messages and warnings to appear in the HTML output. I saw this in another question, and I am wondering how to figure things like that by myself using `?` or similar.

Thanks.

Comment: It's all here: http://yihui.name/knitr/options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked @ the documentation [yihui provides on the knitr site](http://yihui.name/knitr/)?

I also highly recommend checking out his book he recently released [dynamic documents with R and Knitr](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1482203537) he covers everything you'd reasonably use and then some.

You can also easily explore the options in R studio by creating an R chunk

````
}```

adding a comma
```{r,
}```

and pressing tab after the comma and it will give you all the potential options - they are well named and you can easily focus your search more thoroughly. For example, if you noticed the `purl` option you could explore more and find it is for extracting R code from the chunk.
````